# PHP Link to image outside root folder [a href, not img src]

Tags: php, image, hyperlink, root, thickbox

Here's my situation: Images are stored outside root folder. I can access them with an external php file (as it should be) then `file_get_contents` then `echo` then `img src` it then it will show perfectly.

I have thickbox installed and what I want to happen is when a user clicks on the image, it will show in the thickbox enlarged

```
<a href="img.jpg" class="thickbox"><img src="my_image_processing.php?img=img.jpg" />
```

I'm trying to create a gallery upon clicking. What happens is the thickbox shows up but the image doesn't. Instead of the image, the gibberish/garbage codes show up with black diamonds with a questionmark. I suppose this is the raw code of the image.

How can I output that as image and not raw code in

```
<a href> 's
```

ADDED: I just played around with it a bit more. When I remove the thickbox class, the `a href` actually works. It displays the image normally on the next page. Unforunately when I attach the thickbox classes, it shows the thickbox, but it shows the raw code

Comment: Based on what you are saying (direct access to my_image_processing.php?img=img.jpg works) I would guess the issue is with thickbox (actual bug or a mistake on your part). Double-check you have followed all the [instructions](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) including the macFFBgHack.png bit. If you are still having problems I suggested you edit/retag your question and include all the thickbox-related script/link/style tags (all relevant HTML) and tell us what version of jquery and thickbox you're using. It looks like thickbox is not sending the image with the jpeg MIME type for some reason.

Comment: Yes, the problem is related to Thickbox, but it is rather the fact, that Thickbox recognizes the content as a page (is assuming *.php is not an image) and does not look into the `Content-type` information sent in headers. The possible solutions are within my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you are using the jpg file directly, it should be something like:

```
<a href="my_image_processing.php?img=img.jpg" class="thickbox"><img src="my_image_processing.php?img=img.jpg" />
```

That is, the php page that read the hidden folder and return the image.

Comment: yes sorry, mine's written that way. I've been pulling out my hair about this for days

Comment: @user657896 I updated my code, the call to the php page should be in both places, also in the `<a>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

If you see the raw image data as text, probably your browser does not recognize the output as an image. You can signal the right mime type with the header line above.

It is also possible that an error occures and error messages make the image file unreadable (because instead of the headers the stream starts with an error message). In that case you should see the error message before the characters.

Comment: I've tried attaching that header on top and even after the codes. Both doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is that Thickbox does not use MIME type information to display the content (see my answer). But the Content-type should be added anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Thickbox recognizes the type of the resource linked by the file extension to determine, whether it is an image to be displayed, or not. It also ignores the query string when determining extension. Thus, you have the following options:

- use some custom URL rewriting and make your script work eg. using URL like `my_image_processing/img.jpg` instead of `my_image_processing.php?img=img.jpg` (search for more info on "mod_rewrite"),
- rewrite the code of ThickBox (or search for option parameters allowing you to change that recognition mechanism without changing the code - I did not find any), or
- implement other library allowing you to implement what you need (and allows you to use the external script in a way you intended),

One thing is making Thickbox think it loads image, not a page into the frame, and the second one is - as **vbence** pointed - adding proper mime type to the image you return with your script: you should add appropriate header with "Content-Type" information.

**EDIT:**

The code responsible for displaying images begins as follows [sic!]:

```
var baseURL;
 if(url.indexOf("?")!==-1){ //ff there is a query string involved
  baseURL = url.substr(0, url.indexOf("?"));
 }else{ 
     baseURL = url;
 }

 var urlString = /\.jpg$|\.jpeg$|\.png$|\.gif$|\.bmp$/;
 var urlType = baseURL.toLowerCase().match(urlString);
if(urlType == '.jpg' || urlType == '.jpeg' || urlType == '.png' || urlType == '.gif' || urlType == '.bmp'){//code to show images
```

You may wish to add another type ('php'), if you choose to modify the script yourself, but you should be aware of the consequences.

**EDIT2:**

If you go with the 'change plugin' option, there is some alternative ([ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)), that makes you able to decide without the need to dig into the code, whether the *.php link should be treated as image. Just look for the `photo` option within [the documentation](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) (when set `photo=true` should behave as you would expect).

Comment: ok, I just tried rewriting it to my_image_processing/image.jpg. I don't get the garbage anymore, but now it just shows up as blank. again when I remove the classes, it works normally. I'll try your edits 1 and 2...

Comment: onto editing the thickbox.js itself, I tried adding |\.php$ in the urlString and/or adding

Comment: and/or adding a urlType == '.php' , but it doesn't seem to work; just a blank screen still. How would you go upon adding that change? I'm sorry I'm not so well-versed when it comes to javascript

Answer (score 0):

You've probably neglected the http headers for displaying an image.

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;");
```

Comment: He says image shows fine when he uses the processing page, that's not the problem.

Comment: I guess the OP does not want the file to be prompted for download, instead just displayed.